# how to fix a malformed JSON in php

Tags: php, parsing, json

i have this JSON string that i want to decode it with `json_decode();` function

```
{"phase":2,"id":"pagelet_profile_picture","css":["VCxcl","Ix2pq"],"js":["fZYUE","VfnZ3"],"content":{"pagelet_profile_picture":"\u003cdiv class=\"profile-picture\">\u003cspan class=\"profile-picture-overlay\">\u003c\/span>\u003cimg class=\"photo img\" src\=\"http:\/\/profile.ak.fbcdn.net\/hprofile-ak-snc4\/222_111_2222_n.jpg\" alt=\"bla bla\" id=\"profile_pic\" \/>\u003c\/div>"}}
```

there is the `json_last_error();` but it not helping me. (got JSON_ERROR_STATE_MISMATCH and JSON_ERROR_SYNTAX sometimes)

i want to know what wrong with this JSON string and how i can fix it automatically in PHP so i can decode it.
some code will be very helpful
thanks.

Comment: do you mean you want to *decode* the string?

Comment: Err… you **have** a JSON string and you want to **encode** it as JSON? Encoding means turning an object or array into JSON. You can't start with a string, and if you already have a JSON string then you probably don't really want to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a json lint, it seems the problem is the src\=

the \ escapes the = sign, which makes no sense.

If you replace src\= with src= it passes the validator.

The fix:

1. Fix the code that generates the json string in the first place.

or

1. use [str_replace](http://php.net/str_replace) to change 'src\=' to 'src='

Answer (score 1):

The problem with a wrong encoding is that it's just a wrong encoding. Things then break.

If the problem is related to invalid escape sequences as Ben pointed out in his answer, you can try to fix the input string for these sequences, probably with a smarter algorithm that is looking for any not-needed escape sequence replacing it with it's non-escaped value by removing the escape character `\`.

You can do so by creating a list of characters that need actual to be escaped, then parse the whole string for the escape character, if found, check if the next character requires escaping or not and then act upon.

However that's only one strategy and as the input is not properly encoded, it's not easy to just fix things because they are already broken.